# How to disable Large Cursor after installing Ubuntu with Accessibility Option ON (High-contrast,..)

Tags: themes, cursor, accessibility

While installing Ubuntu, I accidentally hit the high contrast option. I could not figure out how to disable it within the install, so I let it complete.

I booted up into Ubuntu 13.04 and high contrast was still on. I disabled it in Universal Access, and now am noticing my mouse cursor is huge in web browsers.

This is very much a stock install.

Is there a setting to disable the HUGE mouse? I mean the thing is 4 times the size of text etc on normal pages.

Looks like it's in everything with text.. terminal, app store, folders and files...

Answer (score 0):

Using a graphic interface:

1. Install Unity Tweak Tool
2. Run Unity Tweak Tool → Cursors: Uncheck Use Large Cursors

Otherwise, a quick fix:

1. Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. Run:

   ```
   dconf reset /org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-size
   ```